# HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting 404 error while clicking on the menu of page after login. I'm using VS2010 and testing it on local. When I'm clicking on my menu option (menu name: changepwd) directly it's redirecting to some other page http://localhost:6205/user/changepassword.aspx (error 404) but when I'm clicking on other menu option(menu name: queue) then if I go to menu (changepwd), it's redirecting to correct page http://localhost:62058/HelpDesk/user/changepassword.aspx (no error), it's showing no error and application working fine. This only happens if I go to changepwd directly.

I have navigation menu bar (home, ticket, queue, changepwd, contact). So when after login this navigation bar appears and when I'm clicking on changepwd it's showing 404 error and when I'm clicking on queue first and then if I navigate to changepwd it's working fine.

Comment: explain more about your question

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:62058/HelpDesk/user/changepassword.aspx
 http://localhost:62058/user/changepassword.aspx

HelpDesk folder is missing in your second url so its throwing 404 error
Place HelpDesk in your navigation path then its work fine.